# Error in the reasoning

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Here is a question.
Find  an error in the following line of reasoning

> $$\int \frac {\cos x}{\sin x} dx , \left( \frac 1 {\sin x} = u,\cos x\,dx =dv, du=-\frac {\cos x}{\sin^2x} \, dx, v=\sin x \right) \\
> \int \frac { \cos x}{ \sin x} dx =\frac 1 { \sin x} \cdot \sin x +\int \sin x\frac {\cos x}{\sin^2 x} dx=1+ \int \frac {\cos x}{\sin x} dx =2+\int \frac {\cos x}{\sin x} dx =\\
> =\cdots= n+\int \frac {\cos x}{\sin x} \, dx \\ 0=1=2=\cdots=n$$

I think error is linked with the constant ,where every integral should differe from each other by constant.Is my thought correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That $\displaystyle\int f(x)\,dx = 1 + \int f(x)\,dx$ need not trouble you.

The expression $\displaystyle \int f(x)\,dx$ isn't really a precisely defined thing; when one writes $\displaystyle\int f(x)\,dx = g(x) + C,$ it just means that all functions differing from $g(x)$ by a constant are antiderivatives of $f(x)$.

Every function that is $1$ plus some antiderivative of $f(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten that the $uv$ term is a function.  It is not the constant 1, it is the constant function $uv(x)$=1.  When you evaluate it as a definite integral, the $uv(x)$ will be evaluated at the lower and upper limits of integration, which will be subtracted, yielding zero.

*Actually, strictly speaking, $uv(x)$ is undefined at 0 and all multiples of $\pi$.*